# PHP Progress Bar: % Of 2 Numbers

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, percentage

I have a problem with a Progress Bar percentage. I'm creating a vote system (Yes/No) with a MySQL database and if the 2 numbers together are exceeding 100, the progress bar does not work properly.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTpdM.png

All I need It's to 'convert' the numbers to the percentage, even if the votes are exceeding 100. For example, If there are 1000 votes (750 for Yes, 250 for No), the result should be '75% Yes and 25% No'.

Thank you in advance!

```
    <body>
    <?php
        define('HOST', 'localhost');
        define('USER', 'root');
        define('PASSWORD', '');
        define('DB', 'rating');

        $db_connection = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB);

        $SQL_REQUEST = "SELECT Yes, No FROM `ratings`";

        $RESULT = $db_connection->query($SQL_REQUEST);

        if($RESULT->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while($ROW = $RESULT->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $gp = $ROW['Yes'];
                $bp = $ROW['No'];
            }
        }
    ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-margin-top">
            <div class="transparent">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        Rate It
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:<?php echo $gp ?>%"><?php echo $gp ?>% users voted Yes</div>

                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width:<?php echo $bp ?>%"><?php echo $gp ?>% users voted No</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You overwrite the `yes`, and `no` on every iteration.</s>

```
while($ROW = $RESULT->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $gp = $ROW['Yes'];
    $bp = $ROW['No'];
    }
```

You reassign the value. I'd do:

```
$gp = 0;
$bp = 0;
while($ROW = $RESULT->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $gp = !empty($ROW['Yes']) ? $gp + 1 : $gp;
    $bp = !empty($ROW['No']) ? $bp + 1 : $bp;
    }
```

or if `$ROW['Yes']` and `$ROW['No']` are tinyints....

```
$gp = 0;
$bp = 0;
while($ROW = $RESULT->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $gp += $ROW['Yes'];
    $bp += $ROW['No'];
    }
```

Since you only have one row you don't need to loop the fetch.

```
if($RESULT->num_rows > 0)
   {
        $ROW = $RESULT->fetch_assoc())
        $gp = empty($ROW['Yes']) ? 0 : $ROW['Yes'];
        $bp = empty($ROW['No']) ? 0 : $ROW['No'];
        $yes_vote_average = round(($gp / ($gp + $bp)) ,2) * 100;
        $no_vote_average = round(($bp / ($gp + $bp)), 2) * 100;
   }
```

then use the `$yes_vote_average` and `$no_vote_average` in the `<div>...</div>` outputs respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but no one from your methods does not work.

Comment: Can you rephrase that? Is there an error? incorrect data? Is there only one row in the table with a percentage?

Comment: That's what I get from your first method: http://i.imgur.com/mUHoPuv.png | Second method: http://i.imgur.com/tigchd9.png | These are the values of my DB: http://i.imgur.com/q5L1VIv.png

Comment: This answer also always assumes `$RESULT->num_rows` is always true, if not you're going to get undefined variable errors. You could initialize the variables to a default value to avoid that. If this resolves your issue please remember to accept it.

Comment: Did you use the new variables?

Comment: Yes, I used them.

Comment: Update your question in that case. The `214%` should not be being echoed if the correct variable is being used; it would output `.75.....%`. I updated the math functions to display a whole number but that isn't your current issue. https://eval.in/630390

Comment: @chris85 `style="width:<?php echo $gp ?>%"><?php echo $gp ?>% users voted Yes</div>` and `style="width:<?php echo $bp ?>%"><?php echo $gp ?>% users voted No` OP's code; they're echoing the wrong variable which should be `$yes_vote_average` and `$no_vote_average` respectively. Least, that's what I get from all this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yea, that's my thought too. I think they missed the `then use the $yes_vote_average and $no_vote_average in the output.` at the end of the answer.

Comment: @chris85 I am pretty sure you're right on that one.

Comment: It's ok guys, It works fine. Thank you for your answers, really appreciate. Have a good day!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks.